# Issues within code around Leap Year using datetime (beginner help)

Tags: python, web-scraping

My question is that whenever there is a Feb-29 result this causes a leap year issue with datetime.strptime. Ebay doesn't have a year attached so I believe from reading it automatically registers 1900 as the year. I don't know how to set it so that the current format is '%b-%d %H:%M' to something like '%y-%b-%d %H:%M' or where '%y' is i put in something that says year = whatever.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

    for container in search:

        #Date Sold
        sold = container.find('span', class_='s-item__ended-date').text
        soldd = datetime.strptime(sold, '%b-%d %H:%M')
        solddd = datetime.strftime(soldd, '%d-%b') 
        Date_sold.append(solddd)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of an input that causes the problem?

Comment: Hey Anwarvic, Not sure how to best display the issue but I search for something on ebay with a sold on Feb-29 sale and this was the outcome. `code` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ebaypricehunt.py", line 47, in <module>
    soldd = datetime.strptime(sold, '%b-%d %H:%M')
  File "C:\Users\Dazza\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 588, in _strptime_datetime
    return cls(*args) 
ValueError: day is out of range for month `code`  I can copy out my whole script/code into my whole question if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you want to convert a given date with a custom year. So, for example: `Feb-29` can be converted into `[year]-02-29` where `[year]` can be changed based on your choice.

If that's what you want, then you can simply append the chosen year into the data before converting it. So, it would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

sold = "Feb-29 13:05"
year = "2020-"
soldd = datetime.strptime(year+sold, '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M')
print(soldd)
# 2020-02-29 13:05:00
```

As you said in your question: if you didn't pass any year while `strptime`, this function will assign `year = 1990` which isn't a leap year. So, this given date (`Feb-29`) will throw this error:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

So, you need to make sure that the year you're going to choose is a leap year. And here are all the leap years in the past decade:

```
leap_years = [1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1940, 1944, 1948, 1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020]
```

Comment: absolute legend you helped the issue.

Comment: Glad I could help!